# infopath list form display rules do not work in IE

Tags: 2013, web-part, infopath, list-form, ie-11

Infopath 2013, SharePoint 2013 in Office 365

The Infopath created list form is embedded in a SharePoint page as a web part.

The Infopath created list form works in Edge & FireFox - I have checkboxes that hide/display sections via rules.

I have not even used any code, only creating the list forms in InfoPath itself. So there is no console.log or any other code to remove...I believe.

also: the content meta tag is already set to Edge:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
```

also: note that when I look at page source in IE 11, there is a lot of scripts AFTER the end html tag:

```
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var g_duration = 884;
    var g_iisLatency = 2;
    var g_requireJSDone = new Date().getTime();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="spOnePageContext">

    var __onePageContext = {};
    ...etc
```

So, in IE 11, the same checkboxes do nothing.

How do I get the Miscrosoft IE 11 browser to treat the List Form the same way FireFox or Edge does?