# Sharepoint Problem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, list

Infopath 2013, SharePoint 2013 in Office 365

The Infopath created list form is embedded in a SharePoint page as a web part.

The Infopath created list form works in Edge & FireFox - I have checkboxes that hide/display sections via rules.

I have not even used any code, only creating the list forms in InfoPath itself. So there is no console.log or any other code to remove...I believe.

also: the content meta tag is already set to Edge:

also: note that when I look at page source in IE 11, there is a lot of scripts AFTER the end html tag:

var g_duration = 884;
    var g_iisLatency = 2;
    var g_requireJSDone = new Date().getTime();




    var __onePageContext = {};
    ...etc

Please look at this url as a reference [infopath list form display rules do not work in IE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/219907/infopath-list-form-display-rules-do-not-work-in-ie)

So, in IE 11, the same checkboxes do nothing.

How do I fix this issue in IE and MS EDGE thank you

Comment: Are you running IE in compatibility mode view?

Answer (score 0):

I'd be wary of using InfoPath for new forms. I have found that they are finicky and restrict customization at times. I admittedly don't know how to make the check boxes work, but I would suggest using SharePoint Designer to create some new forms. I've had more luck with those. Hope this helps.

Comment: is it possible that I can remove the generated code  

<script type="text/javascript">
    var g_duration = 884;
    var g_iisLatency = 2;
    var g_requireJSDone = new Date().getTime();
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="spOnePageContext">

    var __onePageContext = {};
    ...etc 

if it is possible how ? thanks for the response